# 笑っちまう程 translation in context

Tags: translation, word-usage

I'm a beginner in Japanese. I don't completely get what

> 笑っちまう程 立場が 変わるぜ

means in the context below. Is it something like "The more I laugh the more the situation changes"? It makes no sense to me.

The context:

> 運命・・・か。おまえを捕虜として 国に連れ帰りゃ  俺も一気に 英雄扱いだろうな・・・部隊を全滅させ、部下を５人も失ったくせに 敵と手を組んで オメオメ と生き残った 国辱ものが・・・ **笑っちまう程 立場が 変わるぜ**・・・

Answer (score 0, accepted):

笑っちまう is the colloquial form of 笑ってしまう, here meaning something like “laughing involuntarily/despite oneself”.

程{ほど} can be literally translated as “degree” or “extent” and A程B usually means something like “B to the extent of A” or “so much/enough B that A”.  I.e.

> 笑っちまう程 立場が 変わるぜ

Means

> The situation will change † (so much) as to make one laugh

† The tense should be matched to context

Comment: `The situation changed` --「変わるぜ」なので、過去形じゃないですよね？「国に連れ帰りゃ...英雄扱いだろうな」も過去の話じゃないし

Comment: 日本の本で過去のことも現在自制で語ることがあるのでたまには迷います。修正しました。